# Fpdf Send To back Change order of Cell

Tags: php, fpdf

How to send cell() to the back because it currently show to pdf based on order in the code. This is the example.

```
$pdf->SetXY(10, 20);
$pdf->SetFillColor(240);
$pdf->Cell(10, 10, '', 0, 1, 'L', true); // Show up 1st: Cell 1

$pdf->SetXY(10, 20);
$pdf-> SetFillColor(100);
$pdf->Cell(10, 10, '', 0, 1, 'L', true); // Show up 2nd: Cell 2
```

So, how can I set which Cell will come first/send to the back without follow the order?